# Design my own Error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to design an error in python.

Here is my code

```
class TwitchException(Exception):
   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value
   def __str__(self):
       return "The input ", self.value ," is not a valid reaction."

valid_reactions = ["Poggers", "4Head","SMOrc", "TheIlluminati"]



def react(reaction):
    """
    >>> react("Poggers")
    Poggers
    >>> react("Hello")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    TwitchException: The input Hello is not a valid reaction.
    >>> react("SMOrc")
    SMOrc
    """
    try:
       if reaction in valid_reactions:
           print(reaction)
    except TwitchException:
       raise TwitchException(reaction)
```

Help!!! I am not sure how to fulfill the second doctest.

Comment: You only raise `TwitchException` if a `TwitchException` occurs, so it won't be raised.  Don't you just want to take out the `try/except`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to raise the exception in the `else` clause of the `if` statement; there is no need for a `try` statement here.

```
def react(reaction):
    if reaction in valid_reactions:
        print(reaction)
    else:
        raise TwitchException(reaction)
```

This is, however, typically written as

```
def react(reaction):
    if reaction not in valid_reactions:
        raise TwitchException(reaction)
    print(reaction)
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `__str__` must return a string. Yours returns a tuple:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "The input ", self.value ," is not a valid reaction."
```

It should be:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "The input {} is not a valid reaction.".format(self.value)
```